# Window Resize in jQuery not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the jQuery function below that is meant to remove a class on window load and resize if the width is greater than 992 px and add a class if its less than 992px.

It seems to be working fine however the class stays added if i increase the window size from 992 to 1010px. At 1011px it is removed.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$(window).on('resize', function() {
if($(window).width() > 992) {
     $('.bid-overlay-booking').removeClass('fancyboxID-booking');
}
else{

     $('.bid-overlay-booking').addClass('fancyboxID-booking');
}
}).resize();
});
```

Comment: Seems it would be a lot cleaner if you just used Media Queries in your CSS

Comment: i need to use jquery as the if i use media queries as aspects would be affected

Comment: why do you have resize() at the end ? clearly you first function$(window).on('resize',handler) does the same thing

Comment: When you say *width* are you referring to the width of the Windows application fully, or the width of the window inside the scroll bars, etc?

Comment: @AlbinPaul  want the function to work for both resize and on load

Comment: @AlbinPaul That is common practice to run the function....

Comment: @lurker it would be window inside the scroll bars

Comment: @user38208 " if i use media queries as aspects would be affected" Have no clue what that means, it is basically the same thing of adding the class, the css inside the media query would apply....

Comment: As hinted at in the posted answer, it's probably a matter of choosing the correct width function. See [Device and Viewport Size in Javascript](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/).

Answer (score 1):

I wrestled with something similar a while back. Here was my kludge fix.

```
var windowHeight = 460;
var windowWidth = 800;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
    windowHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
    windowWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
}
if (document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetWidth) {
    windowHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    windowWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
}

if(windowWidth  > 992) {
     $('.bid-overlay-booking').removeClass('fancyboxID-booking');
}
else{

     $('.bid-overlay-booking').addClass('fancyboxID-booking');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does not working with window resize

Comment: @user38208 um,  did you not put it in the window resize event to test?

Comment: You are off by 18px. Perhaps you have miscalculated the 992 value should it be 992+18?

Comment: @epascarello i did..still no luck